# Можно ли преобразовать список в модуль без использования цикла?

Tags: python

возник такой вопрос: как в python получить модуль списка без использования цикла?
Допустим у нас есть список:[1,2,3,-1,-2,4,-4,9] можно ли получить модуль этого списка. То есть [1,2,3,1,2,4,4,9] без использования циклов.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Уточните свой вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот,например, у меня дан список: [1,2,-12,-2,-3,-4,6] Возможно ли получить модуль такого списка(то есть все элементы положительные) без использования циклов. Например используя функции и включения. Просто стало интересно есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: `list(map(abs, [1,2,-12,-2,-3,-4,6]))`

Comment: Спасибо большое !